# Making CodeIgniter use <ControllerName>_Controller by default without changing the library?

Tags: php, codeigniter, naming-conventions

I'm finding I have lots of conflicts with class names when developing for CodeIgniter.  For example, I recently had the situation where I had a Checkout controller:

```
class Checkout extends Controller 
{
    // Contents
}
```

And then went on to create a new custom library:

```
class Checkout
{
    // Contents
}
```

Which would obviously throw an error.

What I want is to be able to define my controllers as `<ControllerName>_Controller` so:

```
class Checkout_Controller extends Controller 
{
    // Contents
}
```

And I want CodeIgniter to pick this up as it would any other controller.  I also want to do this **without** changing any of the core library so that I can update it without re-implementing my changes again and again.

I know you can do this with routing (and it's how I have been handling it so far) but this seems to me to be more like a hack than an actual solution. Is there a way to force CodeIgniter to use the syntax I want with the restrictions I need?

Comment: I'm going to be un-popular for saying this, but I'd give Kohana a try. Hacking something that should make your life easier by default is stupid and annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this article generally "grinds my gears" it does show you how to the _Controller suffix to your controllers.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/6-codeigniter-hacks-for-the-masters/